# Does paint in midair when the match ends still count?

Tags: splatoon-2

When the game ends, does paint still in midair and grenades that haven't exploded still count?

That is, does throwing a grenade at the last second give you a little bit more turf?

Comment: In-progress airstrikes in Splatoon 1 counted towards the total, so I would assume they also count in Splatoon 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, after time runs out, the game will continue to wait for any animations to complete, such as for suction bombs, and add their ink to the final result. This is the same behaviour as the first game.

Comment: This is true, but there are a few different ways it can play out. For example, the rain from Inkstorm will keep going and counting for inked turf, but the game will fade out without waiting for the rain to stop. A Sprinkler, however, will immediately stop producing ink when the match ends.